# how to formulate Lpsum optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to optimize the cost for the vendors `OMP1`, `OMP2`, and `OMP3`. They have the cost - CO and production capacity - OC varying for each month i=1,..,12 as below

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?  This sure looks like a homework problem and SO is not a code writing service.  You will probably want to double index this by (vendor, month) to handle the constraints.  And also figure out why zero (no production) isn't the optimal minimal answer.

Comment: @AirSquid thanks for suggestion, have edited the post with code. output says not fesible solution. can you please help check. thanks & regards,